# Visual Studio Code | Remove the useless Text in "Terminal"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run my code, there is some text standing where the location of the file is (in which folder, etc...) and then after the code is my device name, how can I get remove those text?
I saw some people which didn't had that anymore, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, so if anyone knows, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In the vscode powershell terminal
`function prompt {$null}` should work